# Different popup sizes in ArcGis WebAppBuilder

Tags: popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder

let's asume I have to different Layers in a WebApp built by ArcGis WebAppBuilder. Now I can style the popup style and size by css.
But how could I achieve two different sized popups, one for each layer?
The point is Layer 1 contains a lot of information and Layer 2 doesn't. When I define a popup with 500px*500px(via CSS) it perfectly suits Layer A . But for Layer 2, there is too much empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon layer, dynamically you can change the size of popup using JavaScript and CSS. For more info you can refer below links

[Custom Popup Guide](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_customizepopup.html)

[ESRI Js API custom popup sandbox example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=popup_chart)